# SharePoint 2013:How to display selected item in the list in the webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have 2 webpart in sharepoint 2013. Initially first webpart will display all item from custom list. Another webpart will display a detail record of item selected from webpart 1

Here is the scenario

WebPart 1 display

```
CarMakeID CarMakeName
1         Honda
2         Toyota
```

Webpart 2 display:
If a record selected from Webpart 1 (for instance ID 1), then the ViewItem display in Webpart2. This View Item display is like DispForm.Asp.

Please advise

Comment: And what is your question? Are these OOB webparts or custom webparts?

Comment: THis is OOB Webpart.I am trying to display selected item in webpart 1 in webpart 2 which the display exactly as DispForm.Aspx. So normally when you click item in list in webpart it will display item in DispForm.aspx but it navigate away from the current page. However i want to display DispForm.aspx in webpart2. Is that make sense?

Comment: Using query string webpart will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using next steps:

- Add a lookup field to the document library.
- In SharePoint Designer edit the Display Form the list
- In the Display Form, insert a Data View Web Part for the document
  library. This document
- library has the lookup field to the your list
- Next, with the data view Web Part selected, add a Filter
- Filter on the Field ID, which is the ID column of the Lookup Field.
  For the filter create a new Parameter.
- For the Parameter Source choose Query String. For the Query String
  Variable enter ID. This will create a Filter Parameter that looks
  at the query string and takes the value from the ID parameter. The
  url of the Detail View Form always contains the ID of the selected
  list item.
  Now you have created a filter that will filter the data view web part based on the ID of the item that we are looking at. Because we the field we filter on is the lookup field to this item, we only get the documents that are linked to this lit item.

[link to source](http://blog.orbitone.com/post/SharePoint-2010-displaying-related-documents-in-a-detail-view)